# Vue.js: динамическое CSS-свойство в псевдо-элементе ::before

Tags: css, vue.js

Всем привет, уважаемые разработчики!

Мне необходимо переписать данный пример:
[Pure CSS Puzzle Grid Gallery](https://www.bypeople.com/puzzle-grid-gallery-css/)
на Vue.js.

Проблема возникла, когда я захотел динамически подставлять URL картинок в CSS. Причем не просто в стиль компонента, а нужно попасть в псевдо-элемент `::before`:

```
.puzzle::before {
  content: "";
  /* Пробовал так - ничего не сработало */
  background-image: url(attr(data-src));
  /* Тут также ничего не сработало, даже если data-src обёрнут в `url("${}")` */
  background-image: attr(data-src);
  /* Со статичной ссылкой работает */
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/600/600?image=1011");
}
```

При этом код шаблона выглядит так:

```
<div :class="pieceClasses">
  <div :class="puzzleClasses"
    :data-src="imageSrc"
  />
</div>
```

где imageSrc - это URL изображения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить данную задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл [как привязать динамическое значение к свойству псевдо-элемента](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60031052/12670766)

Динамически устанавливать собственные свойства компонента и здесь же указывать
кастомные свойства:

```
<div :class="pieceClasses">
  <div :class="puzzleClasses"
    :style="`--my-src: url(${imageUrl})`"
  />
</div>
```

Внутри псевдо-элемента нужное нам CSS-свойство будет захватывать значение из нашего кастомно свойства:

```
.puzzle::before {
  background-image: var(--my-src);
}
```

Теперь свойство `background-image` псевдоэлемента `.puzzle::before` захватывает URL из переменной через кастомное свойство `--my-src`.

Однако, должен отметить, что конкретно для URL-ов такая привязка работает не так хорошо, как мне хотелось бы. Дело в том, что браузер формирует кучу запросов на скачивание бэгграунда с каждым тиком анимации! Думаю, браузер просто видит, что свойство нестатично, а значит пытается обновлять бэгграунд с ходом анимации.